# Wordpress show install Screen when site is down

Tags: wordpress

here is my problem. I have a customer website built on Wordpress and hosted on iPower and at three occasion already the server went down on me while I am working. When this happen it shows the Wordpress install screen which is not a good thing. Is there a way to show an image when this happen instead of the install window?

Btw iPower answer to me was that I had more than 75,000 queries in one hour and that I should upgrade my Hosting plan. I find this weird since I was only working on the site for 30minutes when it happend. They also say that I must have a script that was doing this...

Thanks

Comment: your probably trying to solve the wrong problem. If the site is low usage, it could be excessive db queries by menus' etc or a massive posts archive page but if not, install w3 super cache, it can serve static pages which will prevent the problem. But obviously stylesheets will be cached also, so check the settings, or develop locally. Check out `get_ num_queries()` also.

Comment: Do as David said. Try solving your problems first, before you do anything else. 75.000 queries furthermore does not sound normal, how many visitors do you have?